# How to Calculate the Sum of Coefficients in a Polynomial with known Integer Roots

Tags: polynomials

I have this problem:
given $N$,  $1 \leq N\leq 100$ integers which are roots from a polynomial, calculate the sum of coefficients from that polynomial

for example: given $3$ integers $2$, $2$ and $3$, I can calculate the polynomial $$x^3 - 7x^2 +16x -12,$$ so the sum of coefficients is $-2$

but if I have $100$ integers, I think calculating the polynomial will be enormous, so is there some way to find this sum of coefficients?

Comment: your polynomial is monic or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is monic? I'm a computer teacher, and this problem is a practice problem for computer science olympiad in Indonesia

Comment: monic polynomial means a polynomial with leading coefficient (coefficient of the highest degree term) is $1$

Comment: I think it's monic, because if all the roots are integer, so the coefficent of x^N must be 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum of the coefficients is just the value of the polynomial in $1$, hence if the polynomial is monic with roots in $n_1,\ldots,n_k$, then $$p(1) = (1-n_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1-n_k).$$

Comment: I'm sorry, my background is in information technology, so can you explain the idea behind your answer. I have already created a Pascal submission using your equation above and it has been judged correct

Comment: In particular, if $1$ is a root, then the sum of the coefficients is zero.

Comment: And for the given example $(1-2)(1-2)(1-3)=-2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If your polynomial is monic, it can be written as $$P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)...(x-100)= x^{100}+a_{99}x^{99}+...a_1x+a_0$$
put $x=1,$ then $$0=1+a_{99}+a_{98}+...a_1+a_0.$$

Comment: The roots are not necessarily $1,2,\dots,N$.

Comment: Thank you. But I think  question says like that?

Comment: The roots are random integer numbers not a sequential integer numbers. But your answer combined with the answer from Jack D'Aurizio helps me understand how to tackle this problem. Thx